# Repeated measures line plots in pyplot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization

I have a pandas dataframe who's head looks like this:

```
Sample  208Pb   bottle_number   date_collected
0   2   8.133   bottle1 2015-08-01
1   4   1.111   bottle1 2015-08-01
2   7   7.171   bottle1 2015-08-01
3   8   40.630  bottle1 2015-08-01
4   9   1.112   bottle1 2015-08-01
```

And I'm trying to get a plot like this: [RMANOVA plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crZf2.png)

`bottle_number` and `date_collected` are both factors. I've subsetted my original data so that the only `bottle_number` here is `bottle1`, so that's irrelevant. There are three levels of `date_collected`.

So, I'm trying to have `208Pb` be the dependent (x-axis) and `date_collected` be the independent (y-axis).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have matplotlib already installed.
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/matplotlib

I ran this code, this will do what it needs

`from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    import pandas
    df = pandas.read_csv('filename.csv')
    plt.plot(df['208Pb'], pandas.to_datetime(df['date_collected']), 'o-b')
    plt.show()`

'o' is the marker

'-' is the line

'b' is for color (you can use other colors too)

Comment: 'date_collected' is a factor, so that is giving me an error. there are only three different dates. also the more important thing is actually getting lines between the points like the graph I linked.

Comment: How lines between points are constructed? Which point they connect?

Comment: to get lines, you can add a parameter 'o-b'

Comment: I'm still getting `KeyError: 'date_collected'`

Comment: check my answer, i've updated it. Worked for me using your sample data

Comment: hey man... could you please look at the picture i linked? have you looked at it? the point is to have a line for each sample individually. if you don't know how to do it please just say so